# Count all records including the row with no values and on two tables

Tags: mysql, sql

what im planning to do was that it will get all records from the past month from two table(tblshoes, tblpants) and  count how many orders happened as this will be used on a google chart line chart i am trying to get all data from july 30 to 1

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS shoeorder, EXTRACT(DAY FROM tlDate) as pdate
FROM tblshoes
WHERE tlDate >= CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH
GROUP BY EXTRACT(DAY FROM tlDate)
```

Here is what my tables looks like :

```
 tblshoes

sname                            tlDate
Name Here                        2017-07-15
Name Again                       2017-07-14
Name again and again             2017-07-13
Name im tired                    2017-07-15
Name of a patient                2017-07-10
.....

tblpants

    pname                            tlDate
    Name Here                        2017-07-15
    Name Again                       2017-07-14
    Name again and again             2017-07-13
    Name im tired                    2017-07-15
    Name of a patient                2017-07-10
```

Result:

```
shoeorder                      pdate
2                          15
1                          14
1                          13
1                          10
```

What i want:

```
shoeorder           pdate            pantorder
0                   30                 0
0                   29                 0
0                   28                 0
0                   27                 0
0                   26                 0
0                   25                 0
0                   24                 0
0                   23                 0
0                   22                 0
0                   21                 0
0                   20                 0
0                   19                 0
0                   18                 0
0                   17                 0
0                   16                 0
2                   15                 2
1                   14                 1
1                   13                 1
0                   12                 0
0                   11                 0
1                   10                 1
0                    9                 0
0                    8                 0
0                    7                 0
0                    6                 0 
0                    5                 0
0                    4                 0
0                    3                 0
0                    2                 0
0                    1                 0
```

Comment: You have the two tables tblpatient and tblpants, but you select from tblshoes...

Comment: edited it, just some typo :D

Comment: Write a store procedure and pass start and end date. select day by day and insert to #Temp table and Select #Temp

Comment: I don't get this. Your expected result includes day 16, but that day doesn't exists in any of your tables.

Comment: ^i am trying to get all data from july 30 to 1 i'll edit it so that it will be more understandable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use full outer join...

```
select
   coalesce(a.shoeorder, 0) as shoeorder
  ,coalesce(a.pdate, b.pdate) as pdate
  ,coalesce(b.pantorder, 0) as pantorder
from (
  SELECT COUNT(*) AS shoeorder, EXTRACT(DAY FROM tlDate) as pdate
  FROM tblshoes
  WHERE tlDate >= CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH
  GROUP BY EXTRACT(DAY FROM tlDate)
  ) a

left join (
  SELECT COUNT(*) AS pantorder, EXTRACT(DAY FROM tlDate) as pdate
  FROM tblpants
  WHERE tlDate >= CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH
  GROUP BY EXTRACT(DAY FROM tlDate)
  ) b
on a.pdate = b.pdate

union

select
   coalesce(a.shoeorder, 0) as shoeorder
  ,coalesce(a.pdate, b.pdate) as pdate
  ,coalesce(b.pantorder, 0) as pantorder
from (
  SELECT COUNT(*) AS shoeorder, EXTRACT(DAY FROM tlDate) as pdate
  FROM tblshoes
  WHERE tlDate >= CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH
  GROUP BY EXTRACT(DAY FROM tlDate)
  ) a

right join (
  SELECT COUNT(*) AS pantorder, EXTRACT(DAY FROM tlDate) as pdate
  FROM tblpants
  WHERE tlDate >= CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH
  GROUP BY EXTRACT(DAY FROM tlDate)
  ) b
on a.pdate = b.pdate
```

Comment: i am receiving this error     `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'full outer join (
  SELECT COUNT(*) AS pantorder, EXTRACT(DAY FROM tlDate) as p' at line 12`

Comment: MySQL doesn't support FULL OUTER JOIN.

Comment: Ah yeah sorry, I work mainly with SQL Server and Oracle, I didn't know MySQL had this limitation.

Comment: thank you so much for updating your code, this was the answer i was looking for :)

Comment: btw this only show records with dates that have values but i'll just try to search it how

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS shoeorder, EXTRACT(DAY FROM tlDate) as pdate
FROM (select tlDate from tblshoes
      union all
      select tlDate from tblpants) sub
WHERE tlDate >= CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH
GROUP BY EXTRACT(DAY FROM tlDate)
```

Guess you should union both tables and then apply the group by to the result query

UPDATE: Then you need a table with all dates filled (for each day). Use the table and left join the query.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS shoeorder, EXTRACT(DAY FROM adt.tlDate) as pdate
FROM all_days_table adt 
      LEFT JOIN (select tlDate from tblshoes
                 union all
                 select tlDate from tblpants) sub ON adt.tlDate = sub.tlDate
WHERE tlDate >= CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH
GROUP BY EXTRACT(DAY FROM adt.tlDate)
```

Comment: this doesn't select values with shoeorder = 0

Comment: what's the table structure for all_days_table? 

tlDate = date ? and what do you mean by this ? all dates filled (for each day). like 2017-06-30  ?

Comment: anyway, question was answered by josh gifflan thanks for helping anyway upvoted u for the effort of helping me